# Include external javascript into angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I was trying to include external javascript and html into my angular app.

Here is the author's tutorial which works in jsfiddle

```
<!-- header source -->
<script src="https://www.givengine.org/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script> 
<link rel="import" href="https://www.givengine.org/components/chart-controller/chart-controller.html">

<!-- embed the browser in the web page -->
<chart-controller 
  title-text="A 2-minute starter of building a genome browser with GIVE" 
  ref="hg19" 
  num-of-subs="2" 
  coordinate='["chr18:19140000-19450000", "chr18:19140000-19450000"]'
  group-id-list='["genes", "CHi-C_promoter"]'
></chart-controller>
```

So I did it according for my angular app, added the script ref to index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EpiMiner</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <script src="http://localhost:40080/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script> 
  <link rel="import" href="http://localhost:40080/components/chart-controller/chart-controller.html">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```
<chart-controller 
  title-text="A 2-minute starter of building a genome browser with GIVE" 
  ref="hg19" 
  num-of-subs="2" 
  coordinate='["chr18:19140000-19450000", "chr18:19140000-19450000"]'
  group-id-list='["genes", "CHi-C_promoter"]'
></chart-controller>
```

But I got an "chart-controller is not a known element" error. Not too much experience with angular. Suggestion are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to replace app-root with your chart-controller in index.html

Comment: So this can easily turn into a pretty broad question. Move the external scripts to the "scripts" array in your `angular.json` file under the `build` options for the more "angular way" of doing things. As for your component, did you actually create the component.ts files and declare them in the module it's being used? Or is that not familiar to you yet? If not you'll want to go start with some beginner tutorials to catch up on creating / adding components. Cheers

Comment: @MikeOne that will definitely break the project.

Comment: It was just a hunch. This looks like a webcomponent, not directly related to Angular.